# Cannot find SDL.h when

Tags: c++, linux, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to use TTF for the games I want to develop, I'm fairly new to this so I would thank you a lot if you could answer a question for me:

After I followed the installation instructions correctly (at least I hope i did) I tried to compile my project including TTF, but I wasn't able, an error showed telling me that the compiler couldn't find "SDL.h", what shoul I do? I'm using codeblocks if that helps and this is my compiler line:

```
g++ -o bin/Debug/tuctactoe obj/Debug/game.o obj/Debug/main.o -lGL -lGLEW -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL
```

Hope you can answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the "dev" package for `libsdl-ttf`.  On Ubuntu/Debian you can install it this way:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
```

On RHEL/CentOS/Fedora it might be this, but I'm not sure:

```
sudo yum install SDL-devel
```

You can quickly find out if `SDL.h` is anywhere on your machine by running:

```
locate SDL.h
```

If it is installed somewhere, you need to add that path using a `-I` rule to your compilation command, like this:

```
g++ -I/your/path/to/SDL.h # ...
```